# Declare classes based on user input

Tags: c++, class, compiler-construction

I'm attempting to write a compiler in C++ for my simple language, but I'm not sure how I should go about declaring a user-defined class when the language in question declares a user-defined class.

For example, in this supposed language, the user writes:

```
CLASS Foo {
    int bar;
}
```

How would my compiler read that to then subsequently make the equivalent in C++? I would like the compiler to then execute the following code in C++:

```
class Foo {
    int bar;
}
```

The syntax is identical. Is this possible in C++?

Comment: You can certainly write a compiler that outputs C++ (then compile that with a C++ compiler). The whole topic though is much too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @Mat Well, not exactly a compiler that outputs C++. I have a few libraries that are exclusive to C++, and would like a language that acts as a simplified interface to work with these libraries, with the compiler being the bridge that handles variables and such. But what you said did actually give me an idea of where I'd want to be heading.

Comment: This is totally language-agnostic. You parse your supposed language with a parser -- you'll need to read up about parsing beforehand or use some framework, maybe there is one -- then you emit code in your target language using the information you have gained by parsing. If your supposed language is as simple as in your example, you could just map tokens one-to-one, which would not require a fully-featured parser.

Comment: If you intend to map an open-ended set of classes to actual types in your own program you'll fall flat on your face. Instead treat the `CLASS` definition as data. And use a `class MetaClass` in **your code** to hold values of that data. So for your example `MetaClass mc{"Foo", Field{INT, "bar"}};` and so forth.

Comment: @StoryTeller And if the user later **declares** a variable with the class that was defined, how would that then be done in C++? Would you define another `MetaClass` and copy the values of `mc` over?

Comment: @Alaanor - Take a moment to think about what it is you are modeling. Your question strongly indicates you haven't figured out the *what* before jumping into the *how*.

Comment: Are you attempting to create some kind of REPL?

Comment: @FrankC. No, the language closely resembles C++ syntax, but much more simplified, where C++ does the heavy lifting in the back-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is a **transpiler**, converting the source of one language into that of another language, in this case C++.

To achieve this you need to understanding how to map the semantics of your language to the target language. So, start small and iteratively extend as you get the machinery in place. You will face challenges, to name a few:

1. Are my classes just for data or data and behavior?
2. Does my language have inheritance? Single? Multiple?
3. Does my language support the notion of public vs. private?
4. Can the user `include` statements they've made in other files?

Once you've figured out the fundamentals you will then need to ensconce it all in a working framework. Just like a compiler you will have file management, symbol management and resolution, etc. Finally, you need to hook up a tool chain. I assume that you will want the user experience to be:

1. Write source in you language
2. Invoke your transpiler
3. Your transpiler converts source to C++
4. Your transpiler invokes the C++ compiler against what you just emitted
5. Finally, if all goes well, the file is linked to produce executable/library

Comment: That seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you believe so, accept the answer otherwise what is it missing?